# Why won't my data frames merge?

Tags: r, dataset

Okay, so I'm a pretty decent R-programmer, working in it like 3/5 days a week and for the last week I ran into a rather unique problem. I work in R-studio, where I was unable to merge the datasets described ahead

I have 2 datasets:
Dataset **df**: 13287320 observations by 20 variables
Dataset **data1**: 9453 observations by 2 variables

Both **df** and **data1** have a common variable, namely **user**

**df** has multiple copies of users, so it looks kinda of like:

```
user  var2  var3  var4  ........  var20
1a     x     x     x                x
1a     x     x     x                x
1a     x     x     x                x
2a     x     x     x                x
2a     x     x     x                x
3a     x     x     x                x
4a     x     x     x                x
5a     x     x     x                x
6a     x     x     x                x
6a     x     x     x                x
6a     x     x     x                x
.      .     .     .                .
.      .     .     .                .
.      .     .     .                .
etc.
```

Where **data1** looks neater:

```
user  date
1b     .
2b     .
3b     .
4b     .
5b     .
6b     .
.      .
.      .
.      .
etc.
```

Obviously I am well aware that merging generally is done by either `merge()` or if the package plyr is installed `join()`.

***Now for the actual problem:***

When I try to use:

```
x <- merge(df, data1, by="user", all=FALSE)
```

The result will be where `x` has 0 observations by 21 variables

So then I thought, lets try the `join()` function and used the following code:

```
library(plyr)
x <- join(df, data1, by="user", type="inner")
```

Which then resulted in `x` having 0 observations by 21 variables

I tried countless of variations with different types/alls and leaving out the by part, however all resulted the same.

The idea I then had was to actual test if the users of df are in data1 so I tried a subset with the first user, user 1

```
x <- subset(df, user == "1b")
```

The result was a subset where `x` had 3 observations and 20 variables. (1a in the example).

I am kind of at a loss at where to continue next.

An idea I had was to subset the unique users, however I'm not sure how to achieve this

```
a <- unique(data1$user)
b <- subset(df, user %in% c(a))
```

The above code doesn't seem to work either so if anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited the variable name to avoid further confusion**

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. Are you sure that there are no stray spaces in the `user` column of one of your data.frames?

Comment: Make sure that the column you're joining on in both data frames is the same type---either a factor with the same levels or much more simply, a character. I'd recommend just doing `as.character()` on both columns.

Comment: If that doesn't solve it, then post `dput(head(df))` and `dput(head(data1))` to make this reproducible down to the data types.

Comment: Also, in your example, both data sets have a column called `var2`. Is this accurate? If so, you should rename one of them unless you want to merge on it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem, and found that it was because the variables were in fact not matching. Changing to characters instead of factors made this more visible. The variable to merge by included spaces in the second data set.
Cleaning this dealed with the issue for me.

Best of luck!
Marte

Answer (score 0):

You specified `all=FALSE` in your call to merge.  That means that if there is an element in df that isn't in data1 that it won't be included and if there is an element in data1 that isn't in df it won't be included either.  Looking at your example data the user columns don't have anything that match.  That is why it's coming up empty.

If you think there should be matches you'll need to do a little work since R can't know *how* you intend them to match.

Note that by default it will use all the columns that share a common name to do the matching and for something to "match" all the elements in the matching columns need to be the same.  So if you have multiple column names shared between df and data1 you might run into this issue.  If you only want to match on a single column you can use the `by` (or `by.x` and `by.y`) parameter to specify which column to match on.

Comment: I'm well aware what the all=FALSE does, hence why I specified it. Also I know there's matching values, because when I actually select a value from data, and use it to make a subset of df, then it actually gives me back values, hence the issue.

Also I'm afraid there might have been a little misunderstanding regarding the "var2", It is actually different, thus an Edit has been made to avoid further confusion

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion then post a minimal reproducible example. Right now we are going off of what you think describes your data but as you can see this isn't optimal. Give us some data that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know I am late to the game, but I work in RStudio and was stumped by a similar problem.

Do you have a ton  of columns in either (or both) data frames (adding to more than 100)? If so the below may be useful:

It appeared as though no matter what I did that two data frames (df1 4023 by 150 vars, df2 4023 by 23 vars) would not merge when looking at them in the data frame viewer in RStudio after merging using the below command:

```
dfall <- merge(df1, df2, by="lookup")
```

where lookup is unique in both `df1` and `df2`.

When I looked at the data frame viewer in RStudio (the chart icon from the environment window) it appeared as though this command was failing. In reality, this command worked perfectly well but RStudio data frame viewer is LIMITED TO THE FIRST 100 COLUMNS and if you have more than that it doesn't show them. To me that looked like the merge was failing. It took me a few minutes to realize the merge worked fine, but the viewer wasn't showing the merged columns.

Three ways to see if this is happening to you.

1. See if in the environment window in RStudio if your data frame is larger than 100 variables (listed in the `"value"` column). If it is you likely have the same issue.
2. Use the R `head()` command to see the first lines of your merged dataset in the console (which won't trim your columns to the first 100)
3. Write the merged data frame to a CSV and open it up in excel or google sheets (export using below command):

   ```
   write.table(dfall, file="dfall.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
   ```

That will write a csv file to your working directory that can be opened in excel or google sheets. Check the file to see if your merged columns are there.

Cheers.